# how to customize Product Quick view Popup Size?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, datastax-astra

I'm using elementor + elementor pro with Astra theme, everything woks perfectly except quick view. Quick view popup shows scrollbar and shows inside a frame. i tired by making changes in  product catalog and single product settings, but nothing work as expected. anyone can help me ?
[image]